# Access Denied performing PUT file using S3 pre-signed URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Problem: How can I successfully perform a PUT file request to a pre-signed URL where the bucket has the following permissions:

- Block public access = off for all 4 options
- Access Control List = Public Read
- Bucket Policy = empty
- CORS Configuration = PUT

Here is a concrete example of what I did...

I performed a POST to my `presign` endpoint...

```
> POST /dev/presign HTTP/2
> Host: 9xugkdzvch.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
> user-agent: insomnia/2020.2.2
> content-type: application/json
> accept: */*
> content-length: 51

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!

| {
|   "name": "profile_1.png",
|   "type": "image/png"
| }
```

it returned

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  },
  "body": {
    "error": false,
    "data": "https://profilephoto-upload-dev.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA4IWFXQ2GLT2FGUUA&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1593475190&Signature=JO4pNtbXmb56OYiClZhil4hse0c%3D&x-amz-meta-username=foobar&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDmFwLXNvdXRoZWFzdC0xIkcwRQIhAP5kW%2Fj6Y5BiLgAhec3w6bv17CL8QuEabOy7hhhtK81JAiA7pS6IkGE3WtnIcD78%2BOytl1luSdLBkI9fg%2F2GzxpApirUBQghEAAaDDg0MzMwMjAxMjU1NiIMdbMwBimx3k0miN5lKrEFfUAFtMJep90tfYQqwW09Od1HTSaUKkVUqP0eOaQg89vEnplJ%2BCQwKopOF8Ed8AiFAFQ9qJcbtmg39wEqIBa5Z0oOdfDEphRXDmVWX%2BCQvdCCoPbbZeaK2tBg4PN2f%2FL8OBa4AebUMCwnVJVneA7Pf5p7hVKKeP%2BePDfMWYOpChS9smp0UjfoVSKYDDA1GDS4eE%2FTN02KjnLdVOWPqoAOm%2FurDzbs%2FYe8B2xnC6R0%2FpbMrj2j59bHB9d8f2GcKXOfiHpeKff%2BLNYYsSmEAApsiW2N05ZMTAWBZQTUyWy53jFhYrZU11uo8RlzKoJOiI6pNoufk4CtbdtVYLxdvQZuxQm7TRJNMLDAQQcL6qR07N0sxHMeo7IIe5QNLT%2B%2FUwqG4X3FJxhYHnSvP7CRT%2FtlS%2Fxutl3rNpthpxDplRBDMtc5rSig6H%2Bb9O1vFZKAG%2B%2F9J%2BE4sCWfckh7kANCYA%2BY3bDHvkTj%2BKKWckzpQB4yLyPD4L%2FbiUDm9T520C9ROwXXhMAun%2BI2hxidauOTkyx%2Bzny5M8zTMN8gvVcxlIHgQHCYy6776WdI2qk%2FmKxYM814s74zt4o3AhtIDTJfEJV0NriqcwxOzZqsnGXPBP9fxri5t57M%2B%2BeONpjcFJpRhj%2B1Os1omCe3CL1R84RsrVPfc8FzGu12yM15FeI0Qb5duqgH3kWdc6wEflRsGPWPfVqHdWfj8euhGQXwsE2m4tcglZdYCpxWfMnbF%2Foz8TOJv9b3ODFrYNTtaeG9arUbLZ8CPqWH8Nyag4MNRgZAZRJNHbc4eBKqi9YHp1p%2FCillnFgmoPMwccyziv%2BGAPkjtS9KCLb0XWEwJwJLgLWNllVka9g%2BlODt6HK2mPb0zPLpsQuDI5qQwnBlSWPbhqwpoWyatvmV7aPaeF3dJm5yBVKAMyAwqPbp9wU6zQLBnlCtwUNRh0HMSUwfPWoFlpweESBTUzjEQFRui7g874ksQtlF51dpUsdXF7JI1kV%2FWr8A%2BxhxlMEjxyhoTj70hUVO7V55I7Ppx3Iyz5AlBAoh2nu4NZccHY4JYjU3de%2FYWVa0jfBSxP0WU%2F5GHbwbENjCpgEMhpDVcFf409UN8ecQi53nQh8ytjsDJMTwYalBM8ys1BfXdvLMkL2dtBFTfHtVjIGtrOkTxfH3CtbT24CzAtWrXxBCY%2BDd97o3oi6ztloybTJtxhI8Zdb6vojsFm95QVmVAVO5PaeZ%2BgHOoqHFHJ%2BXG1kbV8OexmT1S1bAXuu%2Fa07HDjJzqBYovvzWa%2BaG9pG8SKiw0N%2Bb5mdxMDdcGEqVIMwUK7mf7sY06Z%2Fbl1SQvErfpEsgA67C1Qtrgb0fKetVMlQR4Zq%2F53H%2FrFrys2OAnPXUfVLiqWY%3D",
    "message": null
  }
}
```

I then used the url within `data` to perform a PUT request and it failed with [AccessDenied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLvrm.png)

```
PUT /profiles/profile_1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA4IWFXQ2GPP2VWPFE&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1593513254&Signature=vmXn5%2Fk%2Bk3hh98B8OeNlU%2F8XetY%3D&x-amz-meta-username=foobar&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDmFwLXNvdXRoZWFzdC0xIkcwRQIhAK6oeGhiy%2BuWwonWYViWa5pzJxZlSwB5MWjuLcZas6NvAiBmArs%2B8noZacruG0dlWrUyIUm30WFLKUYACVW2xMCFmyrUBQgrEAAaDDg0MzMwMjAxMjU1NiIMgQFekIbk3lBaS%2BmyKrEFBrdMyiCwa1iKVcgFxO%2BW1RTCu5M9aKotfJtBCxtW8gGkUY8VsMsVLPYUDWrJU07z7QjdRIK5xR3%2BdWtkK%2FvW6ZULjqrtVwiDbwnncug7FvvzWBCzc2oOVUFenSBNXhr%2FGnlCbqk6mFyqkOtCeFffOYtls19tU56GsSa1aaTwdwQcRld02G1TJCgj6egjgxSoHqDFbntlHU84vWcW5wi1O4YX4NwAEhWmiLC%2BU6RsfbR0NA%2BzJHlRGShJhEAY1pxOmm3533DAzSjlhj3yvTJN8whT4jFUEvn0jWFCLb3u9rC99%2FwjgtPH0jlU%2BqESTP0VlATuCU%2F5by1iTyX4TLRFyF0vCqx5%2BEePH0SdZeVDEqi%2BIgXIkOGG8fzJQkxLu536uCioSojmRYqiG16Osu9mAiP08LEGsIquzsIoIZmWve3P56gwk0pM28TWYz%2BhZtynJCXAIDOtm1gZ7j14ho1SrpIazM6fJ95NgmuqJfud%2BIGbXdytPZQj1jRsj2fH3vlw66LTXN6AKBVPy6yTf45fMBfP2mywSZwkQtjEQ6hVN76nKD6Z1jZ%2F2Pbk%2FpFUwtcfYbGeKDIEpnV6h2%2BvsiaaNmos9eIYLkt6R9glYvInnIYvp6TOKJoicZgv%2BChr1lY8L728wCXnKLXxHTnv1YTnE5z%2FmtMbG4ZxYkj0ioaJt6kS2%2B3Lh%2BXdrbnwK7gbn3rFGT9EaTyeLSOymIB%2BHzAAfxB902g0c4jV6Em6B9xUxUgfXjHY1I5Gla1t36lEgAe7rlfngUlhoomJjDpMCw4IbzFnjvjXdAIzj7cJjmY%2FPxhdy4gp3pRvcgTkJ%2BV9DV8x2vMSgZS1qX5v%2FMQ%2BSQLStK5aY%2FjKqYkBt03102M1NovHpYiaV4XdE6%2F53unpdEyKtsKjUwYGLebd21kUhHkfoX4woqPs9wU6zQJwdh2wOJcRW9Wp6GmVLOyxfI23RxkAgygOjN5R1AUr%2F%2BehPrSr9iQsYjI%2FWzJqi7Ohzr3kZqjXuL4Yi1UKyRF6vyKckSDMQb371HypXkopMuoPxmNpZqI42IwO8%2BM0ktrJfnJ7Kp4i3EDw9eujy6Cuau5fsD8v6s0c3m5hNu1gmESfdmZr1%2BR%2FCVbifqgeLLwyGak96UyO%2BapQ4kOU6tu5uNskL1ewx%2F2K0esKq6qEz1IXA%2Fx5n5dioiom3GI9QVRfrtF7Z%2BhqBLipVfHMR2Pb4N3egoqBj80ux9u0UzYZ8rLst7Ns0tlJzmCHGxh0py9M7kUPAQmVMdQE4rAlP2FjMQiMWpOCiqo4uwADjKrlwinhSc98LPGYTxJ%2F8QveSfixbeZmgdC1gJkOAMUEdgnoh%2BeRB1dHR%2B3SavrFp1EIudMDIUxd4AxZSDYN%2F%2FY%3D HTTP/1.1
> Host: profilephoto-upload-dev.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: insomnia/2020.2.2
> Content-Type: image/png
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 578256
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>A6037105527AC3DE</RequestId>
  <HostId>KqRDTOrRWDTjnQesY9ZIbBb95/lmqLmro7YLETogaA6qu4n0Jq8znwtExBxdpjDhgXr2Lg/MyqU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

For the given:
Here is my `presign` code...

```
import S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3")
import * as mime from "mime"

const createPresignedPost = async (key: string, contentType: string): Promise<string> => {
  const s3 = new S3()
  const params: S3.Types.PutObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: "profilephoto-upload-dev",
    Key: `profiles/${key}`,
    ContentType: contentType,
    Metadata: {username: "foobar"}
  }
  return s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject", params)
  .then(some => {
    console.log(`returned: ${some}`)
    return some
  })
}

app.post('/presign', async (req, res) => {
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  }
  try {
    const key = `${req.body['name']}`
    const mimeType = mime.getType(req.body['name'])!
    const presignedPostData = await createPresignedPost(key, mimeType)
    res.status(200).send({
      statusCode: 200,
      headers,
      body: {
        error: false,
        data: presignedPostData,
        message: null
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.trace(JSON.stringify(error))
    res.status(500).send({
      statusCode: 500,
      headers,
      body: {
        error: true,
        data: null,
        message: error.message
      }
    })
  }
})
```

This express route belongs to a lambda created here...

```
  presignedpostdata:
    handler: ${self:custom.${self:custom.stage}.handler}
    role: arn:aws:iam::843302012556:role/service-role/auto_presignedpost_dev-role-w7qof39g
    events:
      - http:
          path: /presign
          method: post
          cors: true
```

The role ARN mentioned has these permissions...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::profilephoto-upload-dev/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

finally, the S3 bucket is created like so...

```
    ProfilePhotoBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
          BucketName: profilephoto-upload-${self:custom.stage}
          AccessControl: PublicRead
          CorsConfiguration:
              CorsRules:
              -   AllowedHeaders: ['*']
                  AllowedMethods: ['PUT']
                  AllowedOrigins: ['*']
```

Comment: I haven't dug into your code deeply, but I think you need the appropriate auth headers on your PUT request.  The signed URL isn't enough.

Comment: @Brad can you please point me to the right direction on what `appropriate auth headers` are you talking about?

Comment: I'll check back later... I have some code using PUT from the client successfully.  Come to think of it, I might only be using the headers because I also specify `x-amz-acl` and `Cache-Control`.  One or both of them weren't able to be set in the signed URL.

Comment: @Brad thanks I'm really looking forward for a working example coz I'm running out of ideas how to get through the AccessDenied... AWS isn't providing any helpful logs either on the AWS console side...

Comment: If you can show the actual HTTP PUT request and response, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Brad updated my post with the PUT request (please check above). It is just a simple PUT request pointed to the presigned URL with a file payload.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because the browser was sending additional headers like "Content-Type" **but** this header was not configured when generating the presigned URL.

The solution that I chose was to set the header to `application/octet-stream` at the moment of generating the presigned URL **and** on the browser I forced the `Content-Type` header to be `application/octet-stream`.

```
    s3_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod="put_object",
        Params={
            "Bucket": "my-bucket",
            "Key": f"some-key",
            "ContentType": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        ExpiresIn=24 * 60 * 60
    )
```

Obviously this solution was the best for me at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the problem is that you should be using `s3.createPresignedPost` instead of `s3.getSignedUrlPromise`, and then you must use the POST method and not PUT when sending the request.

I think `s3.getSignedUrlPromise` requires you to provide the `Body` of the object at the time that you sign the request, while `s3.createPresignedPost` allows any body to be sent. With `s3.createPresignedPost` you can also add `Conditions` to do certain things, e.g. restrict the max size of the object.

See:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Comment: I can try the post option... but what I don't understand is providing the `body` of the object during signing since that creates a large overhead to the signing function

Comment: It's definitely *not* necessary to use the form POST method for this.  You can use the PUT URL, you just need the right headers.